# How to implement Multi - Select in Material Components for the web

Tags: javascript, html, material-design, dropdown, material-components-web

I am trying to implement material design **Select Component** with multiple selections from **[Material Components for the web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web)**. But I am unable to find any option for the same.

Code for Select. [ [Documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-select) ]

```
<div class="mdc-xyz-inputs-drop-down mdc-select mdc-select--outlined mdc-select--required " style="width:100%">   
          <input type="hidden" name="xyz-input">
          <div class="mdc-select__anchor"
               role="button"
               aria-haspopup="listbox"
               aria-expanded="false"
               aria-labelledby="xyz-label xyz-selected-text">
               
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
            <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">   
               
            
              <span id="xyz-label" class="mdc-floating-label">LABEL</span>
              </span>
              <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
            </span>
            
            <span id="xyz-selected-text" class="mdc-select__selected-text"></span>
            <span class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon">
              <svg
                  class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-graphic"
                  viewBox="7 10 10 5" focusable="false">
                <polygon
                    class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-inactive"
                    stroke="none"
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    points="7 10 12 15 17 10">
                </polygon>
                <polygon
                    class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-active"
                    stroke="none"
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    points="7 15 12 10 17 15">
                </polygon>
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span class="mdc-line-ripple"></span>
          </div>
           <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface mdc-menu-surface--fullwidth">
                <ul class="mdc-list" role="listbox" aria-label="LABEL">
                     
                               <!-- Options Start --> 

                     <li class="mdc-list-item" aria-selected="false" data- 
                         value="1" role="option">
                           <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
                           <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
                              one
                           </span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="mdc-list-item" aria-selected="false" data- 
                         value="2" role="option">
                           <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
                           <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
                              two
                           </span>
                    </li>
                               <!-- Options End --> 
                </ul>   
            </div>  
          </div>
```

How can we change it to support multiple selections in list or dropdown or same component which allows multi-select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation clearly states

> MDC Select provides Material Design **single-option** select menus, using the MDC menu

You'll need to either:

1. Use some other component.
2. Change UI design. It seems that "multiple selections select" is not in Material Design guidelines. Google itself uses different approaches for situations where multiple values needs to be selected. Here are few examples which should give you an idea how to work around "multiple selections select":

**Gmail: assigning multiple labels.**

[image]

**Gmail: multiple addressee**

[image]

**Google Calendar: selecting multiple event guests**

[image]