# How to un-register/unbind a event in material ui with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design

Hi i have problem with `un-registering/unbinding` material components

**Note:** in my real project i'm calling `initializeMaterialComponents` once data is loaded dynamically every time

**Question:** i need to `un-registering/unbind` previous event so that it is not triggered 3 times (+) provide better solution

**Below is my problem `selection triggered 3 times`**:

```js
function initializeMaterialComponents(){
   // console.log(mdc);

    var selectBox = new mdc.select.MDCSelect(document.querySelector('.mdc-select'));

    selectBox.listen('MDCSelect:change', () => {
      alert(`Selected option at index ${selectBox.selectedIndex} with value "${selectBox.value}"`);
    });
}

initializeMaterialComponents();
initializeMaterialComponents();
initializeMaterialComponents();
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

</head>


<div class="mdc-select mdc-select--filled demo-width-class">
  <div class="mdc-select__anchor"
       role="button"
       aria-haspopup="listbox"
       aria-expanded="false"
       aria-labelledby="demo-label demo-selected-text">
    <span class="mdc-select__ripple"></span>
    <span id="demo-label" class="mdc-floating-label">Pick a Food Group</span>
    <span class="mdc-select__selected-text-container">
      <span id="demo-selected-text" class="mdc-select__selected-text"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon">
      <svg
          class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-graphic"
          viewBox="7 10 10 5" focusable="false">
        <polygon
            class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-inactive"
            stroke="none"
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            points="7 10 12 15 17 10">
        </polygon>
        <polygon
            class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-active"
            stroke="none"
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            points="7 15 12 10 17 15">
        </polygon>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="mdc-line-ripple"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface mdc-menu-surface--fullwidth">
    <ul class="mdc-list" role="listbox" aria-label="Food picker listbox">
      <li class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--selected" aria-selected="true" data-value="" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" aria-selected="false" data-value="grains" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--disabled" aria-selected="false" data-value="vegetables" aria-disabled="true" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Vegetables
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" aria-selected="false" data-value="fruit" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Fruit
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Below is jquery example with 3 calls, but works perfectly**

```js
function attachEventListernerToSelectbox(){
    $('#select').off('change');
    $('#select').on('change',function(){
        alert('selected value is :'+ $(this).val());
    });
}

$(function(){
    attachEventListernerToSelectbox();
    attachEventListernerToSelectbox();
    attachEventListernerToSelectbox();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="select">
    <option value="---">--select--</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is because you call `initializeMaterialComponents()` multiple times. When you dynamically add data, don't recreate the listener every time. The `change` listener only needs to be added one time.

Comment: @RandyCasburn please my edit which shows jquery example of calling 3 times

Answer (score 1):

You should move the **selectBox** initialization outside the function and create listener, then you can use [unlisten](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web/classes/_mdc_select_component_.mdcselect.html#unlisten)

```js
var selectBox = new mdc.select.MDCSelect(document.querySelector('.mdc-select'));

var onChangeListener = function(event){
    alert(`Selected option at index ${selectBox.selectedIndex} with value "${selectBox.value}"`);
}


function initializeMaterialComponents(){
    selectBox.unlisten('MDCSelect:change', onChangeListener);
    selectBox.listen('MDCSelect:change', onChangeListener);
}


initializeMaterialComponents();
initializeMaterialComponents();
initializeMaterialComponents();
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

</head>


<div class="mdc-select mdc-select--filled demo-width-class">
  <div class="mdc-select__anchor"
       role="button"
       aria-haspopup="listbox"
       aria-expanded="false"
       aria-labelledby="demo-label demo-selected-text">
    <span class="mdc-select__ripple"></span>
    <span id="demo-label" class="mdc-floating-label">Pick a Food Group</span>
    <span class="mdc-select__selected-text-container">
      <span id="demo-selected-text" class="mdc-select__selected-text"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon">
      <svg
          class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-graphic"
          viewBox="7 10 10 5" focusable="false">
        <polygon
            class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-inactive"
            stroke="none"
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            points="7 10 12 15 17 10">
        </polygon>
        <polygon
            class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-active"
            stroke="none"
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            points="7 15 12 10 17 15">
        </polygon>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="mdc-line-ripple"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface mdc-menu-surface--fullwidth">
    <ul class="mdc-list" role="listbox" aria-label="Food picker listbox">
      <li class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--selected" aria-selected="true" data-value="" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" aria-selected="false" data-value="grains" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--disabled" aria-selected="false" data-value="vegetables" aria-disabled="true" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Vegetables
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" aria-selected="false" data-value="fruit" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Fruit
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, for multiple select how can we do? Please show me for multiple select

Comment: @EaBengaluru check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65083979/6536300)

Answer (score 1):

So the reason why the jQuery version works is that it removes the event handler before assigning a new handler.
And in your version, you create new MDCSelect components by `var selectBox = new mdc.select.MDCSelect(...);`, so JavaScript can't know if the event is attached or not.

One trick you can do here is that adding a new attribute so that you can know that you've already attached the event handler

```js
function initializeMaterialComponents(){
    const element = document.querySelector('.mdc-select:not([event-attached=true])');
    if (element) {
      element.setAttribute('event-attached', true);
      var selectBox = new mdc.select.MDCSelect(element);
      selectBox.listen('MDCSelect:change', () => {
         alert(`Selected option at index ${selectBox.selectedIndex} with value "${selectBox.value}"`);
      });
   }
}

initializeMaterialComponents();
initializeMaterialComponents();
initializeMaterialComponents();
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

</head>


<div class="mdc-select mdc-select--filled demo-width-class">
  <div class="mdc-select__anchor"
       role="button"
       aria-haspopup="listbox"
       aria-expanded="false"
       aria-labelledby="demo-label demo-selected-text">
    <span class="mdc-select__ripple"></span>
    <span id="demo-label" class="mdc-floating-label">Pick a Food Group</span>
    <span class="mdc-select__selected-text-container">
      <span id="demo-selected-text" class="mdc-select__selected-text"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon">
      <svg
          class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-graphic"
          viewBox="7 10 10 5" focusable="false">
        <polygon
            class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-inactive"
            stroke="none"
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            points="7 10 12 15 17 10">
        </polygon>
        <polygon
            class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon-active"
            stroke="none"
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            points="7 15 12 10 17 15">
        </polygon>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="mdc-line-ripple"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface mdc-menu-surface--fullwidth">
    <ul class="mdc-list" role="listbox" aria-label="Food picker listbox">
      <li class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--selected" aria-selected="true" data-value="" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" aria-selected="false" data-value="grains" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Bread, Cereal, Rice, and Pasta
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--disabled" aria-selected="false" data-value="vegetables" aria-disabled="true" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Vegetables
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="mdc-list-item" aria-selected="false" data-value="fruit" role="option">
        <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
          Fruit
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```